# Не запускается в exe формате

Tags: python, exe

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from translate import Translator

terans = Translator(from_lang='ru', to_lang='en')
print('введите вид спорта')
ru_text = str(input())
name = terans.translate(ru_text)

url = f'https://www.sport-express.ru/{name}/'
data = requests.get(url).text
block = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
# print(block)
knoot = block.find('div', class_='se-titled-block__title')
knoot = (knoot.text).strip()
print(knoot)
get_text = block.find_all('div', class_='se-material__title')
for i in get_text:
    print(i.text)
input()
```

При конвертировании в exe файл не запускается с библиотекой translate, без нее все работает хорошо. Причем в консоли запускаются оба варианта. Не подскажете в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть связана с тем, что библиотека `translate` не установлена вместе с вашим приложением. При конвертировании в `exe` файл не все зависимости автоматически включаются в сборку, поэтому нужно явно указать, какие библиотеки нужны для работы вашего приложения.

Вы можете попробовать добавить библиотеку `translate` в список зависимостей, которые будут включены в сборку `exe` файла, используя параметр `--hidden-import` при конвертировании:

`pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=translate your_script.py`

Comment: Большое спасибо, попробую.